# How can i set type curve of edges in Sigma.js v2.1.3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sigma.js

How can i set type curve of edges in Sigma.js v2.1.3 ?  `type: "curve"` don’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no curve edge renderer on sigma 2.x for now